# No sound on TV with HDMI, Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, hdmi

I have connected my Gateway laptop to my TV with an HDMI cord a million times, and I'm aware that you have to go into sound settings and select HDMI Audio. However, since upgrading to 13.04 there is no HDMI Audio option in the sound settings. I'm assuming I need to install something, but I'm not sure what.

Viewing the other questions on the same problem directed me here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages

But I have no idea what to do from there.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Edit this line, from

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.audio=1"
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Restart the system.

Comment: can you explain your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

That is what is called a ppa. It is just a place you can add to apt so it gets updated also. What you need to do is add the ppa to your system and update it... Here is what I did when 13.04 came out and it worked for my HDMI sound issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I added those 3 commands in the terminal, but I'm still having the same problem. HDMI Audio is still not an option in sound settings.

Comment: It is not working from 13.10 on because of message "W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found". The page at http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ shows that raring is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages and install the latest `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-raring-dkms - ** ~precise1  deb` and restart. If HDMI output is not the default selected, select it. Thats it.

I did not find the need to do any of the above suggestions.

I did the same for Ubuntu 13.04 connecting my CPU (Nvidia 450) through HDMI cable to Toshiba 19inch TV.