# GRUB not updated as required, what should I do?

Tags: grub2, updates

I'm running a daily build of Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04 (64 bit). I recently updated, when it mentioned that one of the updates regards the GRUB file, which was edited manually.

I know why it was edited manually (I had trouble detecting HDMI sound in the configuration and did as [this answer suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/300047/134047), which worked perfectly), so I asked to see a side-by-side comparison, intending to apply the changes manually without removing my custom solution.

Then I clicked forward, and... the updates just kept on running. That's it. Now, I'm not sure what I should do exactly - I tried running the updater again but nothing. I have no way of knowing what were the changes, and I'm afraid of restarting the computer after the updates because I have no idea what's missing and what might happen (if anything).

Comment: Note - I reinstalled all grub-efi packages through synaptic, but I'm still too afraid to restart. Please, does no one have a suggestion what I should do?

Comment: The same thing happened to me!  I wish it wouldn't give you these options and then ignore your input.  Scary.

Answer (score 0):

Just revert the file. There is only a line of modification which you can easily find. After the file has been updated, you can easily find it and update it.

In case of multiple differences you can

1. First take a backup of your config file
2. Then revert the file
3. After the update is complete, you can compare the updated file and your backup file using a diff tool and come with the merged file.
4. I use meld for this purpose

Comment: You don't understand - the update already finished. That's the problem. I don't know how to tell it to run again (I tried running updater again but it doens't recognize that there's anything missing)

Answer (score 0):

The way packages are supposed to work (.deb and .rpm), is that each file in nominated as either configurable or not.  If the package manager encounters a configurable file, which is not what it's expecting, it will prompt you during install to either replace the old file, with the new one, save a copy of the new file and leave the old one, or merge them.  Either way it will normally leave files which might allow you to unpick what it did, if you know where the config file is in the first place.  If the file is not set in the package as configurable, then it'll just silently wipe it.

So did you check /etc/default to see if there is an old copy of the grub file?  Failing that, I suggest you run through the solution you listed and see if you can figure it out.  I'd suggest you remove 'splash' and 'quiet' from the settings until you're sure your grub is setup ok (I also use 'text' mode when debugging grub).